# What is the minimum access for updating the Users List?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, permissions

We have a SP2013 site where we're using the Users List for the site collection as a phone list. Ideally, all active users should appear in the list with accurate contact info pulled down from Active Directory. I have created separate views on the list that show the desired columns, with users filtered by Office.

This works for what we want, but the downside is that inactive users still appear in the list until removed from the site collection. I've added a Yes/No column that determines if each person is visible on the Office views, and we would now like to have the admin for each office keep their view up to date by selecting NO on inactive users as needed. However, AFAIK you have to be a site collection admin to modify that list. I'm hoping I'm wrong.

**What is the minimum level of access needed by a user to edit the site collection Users List?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation in sharepoint operating in windows authentication (active directory). if there is any change in the status of any user it wont reflect in the sharepoint and we have go and manually delete/update the user and the same applies when SharePoint is working in forms authentication as well(any user store).

to modify, the user has to be a site collection admin. but as an alternate approach you can develop a custom solution say: asp.net based layouts page with the same logic for modifying the users in the SharePoint.